# Is num_epochs limited in tensorflow's csv file reader string_input_producer()?

Tags: csv, tensorflow

I have a dummy csv file (`y=-x+1`)

```
x,y
1,0
2,-1
3,-2
```

I try to feed that into a linear regression model. Since I have only so few examples, I want to iterate the training like 1000 times over that file, so I set `num_epochs=1000`.

However, it seems that Tensorflow limits this number. It works fine if I use num_epochs=5 or 10, but **beyond 33 it is capped to 33 epochs**. Is that true or **am Im doing anything wrong?**

```
# model = W*x+b
... 
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

# reading input from csv
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["/tmp/testinput.csv"], num_epochs=1000)
reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
...
col_x, col_label = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=record_defaults)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
  while True:
    try:
      input_x, input_y = sess.run([col_x, col_label])
      sess.run(train, feed_dict={x:input_x, y:input_y})
...
```

Side question, do I need to do:

```
input_x, input_y = sess.run([col_x, col_label])
sess.run(train, feed_dict={x:input_x, y:input_y})
```

I have tried `sess.run(train, feed_dict={x:col_x, y:col_y})` directly to avoid the friction but it doesn't work (they are nodes, and feed_dict expects regular data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippets works perfectly (with your input):

```
import tensorflow as tf


filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["/tmp/input.csv"], num_epochs=1000)
reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
_, csv_row = reader.read(filename_queue)
col_x, col_label = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=[[0], [0]])

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
  num = 0
  try:
      while True:
        sess.run([col_x, col_label])
        num += 1
  except:
    print(num)
```

Which gives the following output:

```
edb@lapelidb:/tmp$ python csv.py
3000
```

Comment: For me it doesn't work with greater values of num_epochs (e.g 100.000) or a longer csv file (e.g same lines repeated 1000 times)

Comment: I just repeated the test of the code above with 100.000 epochs and even 1.000.000 epochs both give the same result on my end... perhaps some race condition occurs between fast CPU and slow IO ?

Comment: Thank you for trying out yourself, gave me the force to continue (struggled hours). So the culprits were: `try: except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError: finally:coord.request_stop()` (finally... broke it) and `coord.join(threads)`. I saw that in so many places on internet that I didn't consider removing them, but was better without (or better: was imbricating them in the wrong order). Thanks!